# algorithm for symmetric tree check using recursion with only one function parameter

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

I am looking for an algorithm to check if a tree is symmetric or not using recursion on function with only a single parameter which is root node. I saw this question on leetcode which has simple answer if function has two parameters(root->left and root->right) but I am trying to figure out algorithm with strictly single parameter.

```
bool isSymmetric(TreeNode* root) {
        if(root==NULL || (root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)){
            return true;
        } 

        if(root->left!=NULL && root->right!=NULL){
            return (isSymmetric(root->left) && isSymmetric(root->right));
        }
        return false;
}
```

I have tried the given code but it doesn't check if values of the symmetric nodes are equal. Is the solution for my problem even possible?

Comment: Not really thinking about the algorithm here, but can you just add in checking the value as part of the return?

Comment: By "symmetric" do you mean that the left branch of the root is a mirror image of the right branch?

Comment: By symmetric I mean that the given binary tree's mirror image is same as the binary tree itself. @IanAbbott.

Comment: Please post a symmetric and non-symmetric trees. As examples, to make it crystal-clear.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace

```
return (isSymmetric(root->left) && isSymmetric(root->right));
```

with

```
return (isSymmetric(root->left) && isSymmetric(root->right) && root->left->value == root->right->value);
```

Not sure how the `value` member is named in your code, but you get the idea.

Comment: You could rearrange that a bit to speed up detection of non-symmetric trees: `return (root->left->value == root->right->value && isSymmetric(root->left) && isSymmetric(root->right));`.

Comment: However, I think a symmetric binary tree might need to be a mirror image of itself  and this code doesn't do that.

Comment: @Ian, yes, I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "symmetric" you mean that the left side of the tree is a mirror image of the right side of the tree. In other words, all the values on the left side are mirrored by the same values on the right side.  Here is an example of such a tree:

```
    1
   / \
  2   2
 /\   /\
3  4 4  3
```

Because the nodes to be compared could be widely separated in the tree, this necessitates passing two node pointers to the recursive checking function.  However, you could call that function from a function that takes a single pointer to the root of the tree:

```
// Helper function to recursively check if two branches are mirror images
static bool areMirrored(TreeNode* left, TreeNode* right) {
    if (left == NULL)
        return (right == NULL);
    if (right == NULL)
        return false;
    if (left->value != right->value)
        return false;
    return (areMirrored(left->left, right->right) &&
            areMirrored(left->right, right->left));
}

// Check if tree is symmetric (left and right branches are mirror images)
bool isSymmetric(TreeNode* root) {
    return (root == NULL || areMirrored(root->left, root->right));
}
```

EDIT: Here is a version that uses a "fake" root node at each step of the recursion. It has the disadvantage of using extra storage to store the fake node at each level of recursion:

```
bool isSymmetric(TreeNode* root) {
    TreeNode fake;

    if (root == NULL)
        return true;
    if (root->left == NULL)
        return (root->right == NULL);
    if (root->right == NULL)
        return false;
    if (root->left->value != root->right->value)
        return false;

    fake.value = 0; // fake value isn't used
    fake.left = root->left->left;
    fake.right = root->right->right;
    if (!isSymmetric(&fake))
        return false;

    fake.left = root->left->right;
    fake.right = root->right->left;
    return isSymmetric(&fake);
}
```

Comment: I said that I want to do it with a function that has only one parameter as root node but in your code "areMirrored" function takes two parameters.

Comment: Respectfully, the way you reply to constructive answers doesn't make it easy for us to help you. You replied to my answer with valid concerns, but new information (already tried). You reply to this answer in a bit rude way (I said that). I believe a softer approach would yield superior results

Comment: @ShikhinDahikar Well you could change it to pass a struct or a pointer to a struct that contains the two pointers, but the pointers still wouldn't come from the `left` and `right` pointers of the same `TreeNode`. I don't believe it is possible to do this recursively with a single `TreeNode*`, or at least not with a `TreeNode*` that points to a `TreeNode` in the original tree.

Comment: @Jeffrey I am sorry if it sounded rude totally didn't meant that.